# WCF Diagnostics Message Logging With Unique Id

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, key, unique

I'm logging messages for WCF web service using `System.Diagnostics` `System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging` with configuration below. And I extended 
`TraceListener` class as:

```
public class FormattedTraceListener : TraceListener
    {
        static readonly Logger logger = new Logger();

        public FormattedTraceListener()
            : base(string.Empty)
        {
        }

        public override void TraceData(TraceEventCache eventCache,String source,TraceEventType eventType,**Int32 id,**Object data)
        {
//....
```

```xml
 <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="pretty" />
          <remove name="Default"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="pretty" lockItem="true" type="LoggingTest.FormattedXmlWriterTraceListener,LoggingTest" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>

....

 <diagnostics >
      <messageLogging
                    logEntireMessage="true"
                    logMalformedMessages="false"
                    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
                    maxMessagesToLog="-1"
                    maxSizeOfMessageToLog="134217728">
        <filters >
          <add xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">/s:Envelope</add>
          <add xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">/s:Envelope</add>
        </filters>
      </messageLogging>
      <endToEndTracing  propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

`TraceData` method fired twice (for request and response) for each service call.
However, when method is hit, the `id` parameter is always 0.

I need a unique id in logging text to match request and response log. How can I specify that?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not right. The TraceData(int id) field is not a unique id for the WCF request. It's the application defined code for the event type.

Just use the standard WCF trace classes and [view correlated traces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795(v=vs.110).aspx). If I understand what you are trying to accomplish in matching up request to response, the default behavior already meets your requirements.